# "in what is termed" vs "in terms of"

Tags: meaning

> The First Cause Argument assumes that effects and causes could not
> possibly go back for ever **in what is termed** an infinite regress: a
> never-ending series going back in time.
> [Philosophy: The Basics]

What does **in what is termed** mean? Does it mean "in terms of"?

Answer (score 2):

"What is termed" is used to introduce a term of art (i.e. a technical name for something), in this instance, "termed" is the passive/past participle of "to term" = "to call using the term"

"In terms of" is usually used to say what particular aspect of a topic is being discussed, and is largely equivalent to "with respect to", "as regards", "concerning", or "regarding". There is also a more technical use, mostly found in mathematics, science, and logic where "A in terms of B" means to make all necessary substitutions to express A using B wherever possible. This technical sense is the origin of the more common colloquial case